# missing data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database that is used by a php script to display data... the problem i have is, at what appears to be random occurrences it misses results and I can't see a pattern to establish why it might be doing it...

all the data appears to be fine when i check the database.

here is my initial search page

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

//set variable
$option = '';

// Get the county names from database - no duplicates - Order A-Z
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT tradingCounty FROM offers ORDER BY tradingCounty ASC";

// execute the query, $result will hold all of the Counties in an array
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);


 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $option .="<option>" . $row['tradingCounty'] . "</option>";
}




echo "<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>";
echo "<title>HSB - Latest Offers</title>";
echo "<style type='text/css'>;
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id='wrapper'>
  <p><img src='images/header.jpg' width='400' height='100' alt='header' /></p>
  <HR/>
  Select an area from the menu below to view any offers in that area.
  <form id='filter' name='filter' method='post' action='resultssimple.php'>
        <p><label>County</label></p>
        <select name='result' id='result'>' . $option . '</select>
        <input name='' type='submit' />
        </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>";



?>
```

and here is my results page

```
<?
include 'connect.php';

//Get the details from previous page
$SelectedCounty = $_POST["result"];

// Select offers linked to selected county from form
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM offers WHERE tradingCounty ='" . $SelectedCounty . "'ORDER BY categoryIdName ASC;");

// PREVIOUS ATTEMPTS - ALL WRONG - GGGGRRRRRRRRRRRR !!!!!!!!
//------------------------------------------------------------
//$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM offers WHERE tradingCounty LIKE" . $SelectedCounty);
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pdetails WHERE uid='" . $inputname . "';");
//"SELECT * FROM `offers` WHERE `tradingCounty` LIKE
//$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM offers;");
//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pdetails WHERE uid='" . $inputname . "';");
//$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM offers WHERE tradingCounty=" . $SelectedCounty);


//check to see if results is set - error if not.
if(!$result)
{
    die("<p>Error in listing tables: ". mysql_error()."</p>");
}

//Show all records for selected county
echo ("<p><h2>Showing Latest Offers In : " . $SelectedCounty . "</h2></p>");
echo ("<p><a href='offers.php' target='_self'>back to search menu</a></p>");

/*
echo ("<table border='1'>");
echo ("<tr>");
echo ("<td>ID</td><td>Category</td><td>Business Name</td><td>Business Address</td><td>Address2</td><td>Address3</td><td>Town</td><td>County</td><td>Post Code</td><td>Telephone</td><td>URL</td><td>Email</td><td>Discount / Special Offer</td><td>valid from</td>");
*/

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo ("<div style=' background-color: #EFF5FF; color: #06C; padding: 5px; float: left; border: 1px dotted #06C; margin: 10px; width: 300px; height: 300px; text-align: center; >");
    // echo ("" . $row[0] . "");
    // echo ("</br>");
    echo ("<strong>" . $row[1] . "</strong>");  
    echo ("<hr/>");
    // echo ("</br>");
    echo ("" . $row[2] . "");
    echo ("</br>");
    echo ("" . $row[3] . "");
    echo ("</br>");
    // echo ("" . $row[4] . "");
    // echo ("</br>");
    // echo ("" . $row[5] . "");
    // echo ("</br>");
    echo ("" . $row[6] . "");
    echo ("</br>");
    echo ("" . $row[7] . "");
    echo ("</br>");
    echo ("" . $row[8] . "");
    echo ("</br>");
    echo ("" . $row[9] . "");
    echo ("</br>");
    // echo ("" . $row[10] . "");
    // echo ("</br>");
    echo ("" . $row[11] . "");
    echo ("</br>");
    echo ("<hr/>");
    echo ("<strong>" . $row[12] . "</strong>");
    echo ("</br>");
    echo ("</div>");

/*  echo("<tr>");
    echo("<td>" . $row[0] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row[2] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row[3] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row[4] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row[5] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row[6] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row[7] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row[8] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row[9] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row[10] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row[11] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row[12] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row[13] . "</td>");
    echo("</tr>");
*/  
}
// echo("</table>");
?>
```

what I'm getting can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LY4K.png)

Comment: to be a bit clearer... some results are missing BUSINESS TYPE, BUSINESS NAME and some of the ADDRESS

Comment: Just nitpicking here, but in all your `SELECT` statements I recommend you explicitly name the columns you want to select as opposed to using `SELECT * ...`.

Comment: :) noted Kevin... I guess from an amateurs/my point of view select* was quicker :) and i just had to comment out the lines i didnt want to show...

Comment: Seen inner joins, outer joins, nested loops and merge joins but never a user/browser join before now.

Comment: user/browser join? can you explain so i can maybe fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are they missing or maybe they are obscured by unescaped html characters.  Check the View Source option of your browser to see if they are actually there.  I would especially watch for characters in the data like the Less Than character that the browser may be mistaking for an HTML open character.

You may need to escape your output so the browser does not try to render it:

```
echo ("" . htmlspecialchars($row[2]) . "");
```

Also, I would suggest you never take input directly from a user and put it into a SQL query without escaping it first. You are opening yourself up for SQL Injection attacks.

See the following:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Hi Wes, Can sql injection take place from a dropdown menu? sorry im pretty new to php.

Comment: I've viewed the source, and the missing details are there... why is that happening?

Comment: It's happening probably because the browser sees them as HTML characters.  Do they contain <> chars?

Comment: And... absolutely even from a dropdown.  One could bypass your form altogether and post their own values.  As an example, the Web Developer add in for Firefox allows you to change all dropdowns on a page to text fields.

Comment: here's the source from one of the missing listings, that you can see only half shows up on the screenshot ---        <div style=' background-color: #EFF5FF; color: #06C; padding: 5px; float: left; border: 1px dotted #06C; margin: 10px; width: 300px; height: 300px; text-align: center; ><strong>BUTCHERS</strong><hr/>BOWERS BUTCHERS</br>71 LYNN ROAD
GAYWOOD</br>KING'S LYNN</br>Norfolk</br>PE30 4PR</br>01553 773845</br>rbowers@hotmail.co.uk</br><hr/><strong>10% OVER ?15 SPEND</strong></br></div>

Comment: You have a rogue single quote in your style attribute on the div tag.

Comment: :/ oops. now, thats embarrassing :) It works fine now... however I still need to change a few things highlighted by you guys...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it'll help but in this line:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM offers WHERE tradingCounty ='" . $SelectedCounty . "'ORDER BY categoryIdName ASC;");
```

it looks like you have an extra semi-colon (;) right before the last double quote. I don't think that should be there.

You could also store everything returned in an array and echo everything as you iterate through it to see what it returns. Then, if something's missing, go to your database and look at that row.

```
$tempArray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $tempArray = $row;
}

foreach($tempArray as $value) {
    echo $value . '<br>';
}
```